# Phonegap Camera not working

Tags: cordova, camera

I'm working on a Phonegap app that requires the use of the camera. I took the example from the docs and pasted it into a `camera.js` file. This project is going to use build Phonegap, but right now I'm doing it locally in an Android project for debugging purposes. In addition, I am using jQuery Mobile for the UI. When I go to the `new.html` page, the camera does not show up, and when I click the capture new button, I get an error in the `index.html` page, saying that `capturePhoto()` is undefined, even though I'm calling that function from the `new.html` page. Thank you for any help in advance.

Here is the code for the `new.html` page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
   <head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/camera.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-theme="e">Back</a>
            <h1>New Moment</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">   
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="e" onclick="capturePhoto();" >Capture New</a>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Company Name Here</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="small.png" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="large.png" />
</body>
```

Here is the code from the camera.js file.

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
   console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
   console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
    consoe.log("CAPTURE");
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true }); 
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: By placing the camera.js in the index.html head section it worked. This is kinda weird because I want to run it on the new.html page and display the image their as well.

Comment: Is it new to Cordova 2.0.0 that the <script> references include the assets directory? I can remember from my Phonegap 1.5 project that there is no need for that (base url is assets/www/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing the camera.js in the index.html head section it worked. This is kinda weird because I want to run it on the new.html page and display the image their as well.